# underscore's each checking for {} return of callback

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I was examining how UnderscoreJS implements their `each`/`forEach`

```
//somewhere up top:
var breaker = {};

//then the each function
var each = _.each = _.forEach = function (obj, iterator, context) {
    if (obj == null) return;
    if (nativeForEach && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
        obj.forEach(iterator, context);
    } else if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
        for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
        }
    } else {
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (_.has(obj, key)) {
                if (iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) === breaker) return;
            }
        }
    }
};

//iterator = callback
//context  = optional third parameter of each to provide context in the callback
//obj      = the list
//key      = key of the object (i for index when an array)
```

Basically, it's executing the callback for each item in the object/array. But this like confuses me

```
if (iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) === breaker) return;
```

From what I understand, if the callback returns an object, the loop breaks, but... **Why it's comparing to `breaker` which is an internal object in the underscore module?**. Doesn't it evaluate to `false` all the time since, even if the callback does return an object, it is always `false` since it's not the same object (therefore the loop *never breaks*). What's the reason behind this?

Comment: Another trick that I like, if you need to add values  to the  breaker objects is to instead create a Breaker class and use instanceof tests.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They use `each` internally for e.g. `some`. Since `some` does short-circuit, they can have `each` break there using the "secret" object, while not exposing this feature for regular users. They don't expose the break feature because the native function doesn't do that, either (so their shim is as native-like as possible). If they did, the break feature would only be available if the native function is unavailble, which isn't particularly helpful.