# Underscore's implementation of the Foreach method

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [underscore's each checking for {} return of callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600735/underscores-each-checking-for-return-of-callback)

I was taking a look at underscore's source and implementation of the Foreach method. I just have one question with the below method.

```
var breaker = {};

var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
   if (obj == null) return;
   if (nativeForEach && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
     obj.forEach(iterator, context);
   } else if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
     for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (i in obj && iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
     }
   } else {
      for (var key in obj) {
        if (_.has(obj, key)) {
          if (iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) === breaker) return;
        }
      }
   }
};
```

I am struggling with the following line? Why check if the iterator being called is an empty object? Why would you return an empty object from the iterator?

```
if (iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) === breaker) return;
```

Comment: To abort the iteration (e.g. the `any` predicate, if you found something matching the condition, you don't need to go any further).

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example of the Foreach being aborted. You can post it as answer, and I will mark it as correct. I am struggling to find out where breaker is being set in the library. All I can see in the source is that its being declared as an empty object. I also found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779799/how-to-break-the-each-function-in-underscore-js), which states that with the foreach you cannot break out of the loop.

Comment: I started writing an answer, but then I noticed [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600735) - I think that answer will be sufficient.